# How to make an API call and load data when state is being initialised?

Tags: flutter

I want to populate a list by calling an API when it is being initialised. However since init is not an async function I'm not able to load the value into the list. How can I do this?

```
class _CreateTaskScreenState extends State<CreateTaskScreen>{

 // List<Society> societies;

  @override
  void initState() {

    //societies = await getAllSocieties();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Society>> getAllSocieties() async{
   //API CALL 
  }


    return Scaffold(
....
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an async function/method:

```
methodDoStuff()async{}
```

and call it from your `InitState();`

```
 @override
 void initState() {

     methodDoStuff();

    super.initState();
 }
```

and populate it inside the method itself, with setState():

```
var res = await getFromAPI();
setState(() {
    listToPopulate = res;
});
```